# How to insert into oracle without duplicate rows with Hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have some class Calls

```
public class Calls {
private String Field1;
//and many fields, for example 15
private List<MyModel> models;
}
```

Each minute I get a `List of Calls`

```
List<Calls> list = someService.getCallsList();
```

and try to insert it into DB

```
    Session session = getSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    for(int i=0; i< list.size(); i++) {
        Calls calls = list.get(i);
        session.createSQLQuery(
"INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(CALLS,UNIQUE_CALLS_CONSTRAINT) */ " +
         "INTO CALLS(Field1,....,FieldEnd) VALUES(:field1,...,:fieldEnd)")
    .setParameter("field1",calls.getField1()
    //set all params
    .setParameter("fielEnd1",calls.getFieldEnd();
                if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
                    //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                }
            }
            tx.commit();
            session.close();
    }
```

I need to INSERT row and skip all duplicate: `/*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(CALLS,UNIQUE_CALLS_CONSTRAINT) */`/ For it I use `SQLQuery`

My question is: how can I make this using hibernate without `SQLQuery`? as generally is implemented correctly. I have 15 parameters and I do not want them all to register for `SQLQuery`

Comment: I am understanding you want to de-duplicate Calls object. Is that a possibility that you remove duplicates through a structure like Set and then use that for iteration than a List ? Is that what you need ?

Comment: @Ramachandran G A  a little different. list that I get every minute may contain objects that are already in the database

Comment: Have you evaluated if saveOrUpdate() will help you with the duplicates ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Oracle hint by Criteria,see:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#addQueryHint(java.lang.String)

Comment: I need INSERT where does Criteria?